# HDMI/USB Powered Lighting

Tags: led, usb, hdmi, lighting

Alright so a little vague title but here it goes.

I'm interested in powering some 5v LED strips with an HDMI cable. I have no idea if this is even possible, I'm lacking knowledge in electronics.

My goal is to essentially have some LED lighting turn on when a video game console is turned on and the HDMI signal is fed to the display, and have the power for the LED strip piggyback off the HDMI connection.

Again I have no idea if this is possible, or if it is if it would create a lag in the signal from the HDMI.

Anyone aware of any products like this? or attempted to create this?

The closest I could find was a HDMI female to male with a USB Male lead, but have no idea if that could even provide the power or interrupt the HDMI signal.

Would this be possible to engineer into such a small connector? Is this beyond what the HDMI can provide?

A for sure system I know that can provide what I want is in using an advanced power strip but I was looking for something not so bulky.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI sinks must not consume more than 50mA of current, and HDMI sources must provide up to 55mA with a current limit of no more than 500mA. So no, you can't really power anything directly from HDMI sources. But you can use the 5V power output as a logic signal to control LEDs that are powered from an external power supply. But many HDMI sources just keep the 5V on all the time, so most likely this is of no use.

Comment: Appreciate the fast response, even if it did crush my idea.